# Cannot Get Linked List to Print from Main C++

Tags: c++, string, class, methods, linked-list

I am working on a word cloud C++ program that is suppose to populate a list of words from a text file, put the words in a linked list, then sort the list by frequency and print the list with only one instance of the words and the frequency next to the word.

What I have accomplished is reading the file, populating the linked list, and printing it. However I cannot get the list to print from main instead of the wordCloud method `loadWordCloud()`.  I am not strong with classes yet, so I am sure that is my problem.  But basically I want to call the `printWordCloud()` method from main instead of printing from `loadWordCloud()`.  When I put `getList.printWordCloud()` after I call `getList.loadWordCloud(myFile)`, I get an empty list.  I can see why that is happening, but I cannot figure out how to actually save the list from within `loadWordCloud()` so I can print it later. I am trying to avoid a return statement and keep the method void.

Here is what I have for classes:

```
class wordNode{
public:
    string myWord;
    int freq_count;
    bool black_list;
    wordNode *next;

    wordNode(string aWord);
    ~wordNode(void){};
};

wordNode::wordNode(string aWord){
     myWord = aWord;
     next = NULL;
     freq_count = 0;
}

class wordCloud{
public:
    wordNode *head;
    int size;
    wordNode *nextWord;

    wordCloud(void);
    ~wordCloud(void){};

    void insertWord(string aWord) { insertWord(aWord, false); }
    void insertWord(string aWord, bool blacklist);
    /*void insertWordDistinct(string aWord);

    void loadBlacklist(string fileName);*/
    void loadWordCloud(string fileName);

    //void printBlacklist(void);        // Print the words in the blackList

    void printWordCloud() { printWordCloud(1); }
    void printWordCloud(int freq);      // Print the words with freq or greater freq_count 

    /*void Initialize(void) { nextWord = head; }
    void GetNextWord(string theWord, int *freq_count);

    void freqSort(string sortOrder);    // 'A' = ASC, 'D' = DESC 

private:
    void properlyHandleHeadofList(string sortOrder);
    void properlyHandleRestofList(string sortOrder);
    string upperCase(string text);
    string lowerCase(string text);*/
};

/*void wordCloud::GetNextWord(string theWord, int *freq_count){
    wordCloud aWord;

    aWord.insertWord(theWord);
}*/

wordCloud::wordCloud(void){
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
    nextWord = NULL;
}

void wordCloud::insertWord(string aWord, bool blacklist){
    wordNode *newWord = new wordNode(aWord);

    if (head == NULL)
        head = newWord;
    else{
        newWord->next = head;
        head = newWord;
    }
    size++;
}

void wordCloud::printWordCloud(int freq){
    wordNode *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "No Word Cloud" << endl;
    else{
        temp = head;

            while (temp != NULL){
                cout << temp->myWord << endl;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
    }
    system("pause");
}

void wordCloud::loadWordCloud(string fileName){
    ifstream file;          //variable for fileName
    string word;
    wordCloud newList;

    //newList.Initialize();

    file.open(fileName);    //open file

    while (!file.eof()){
        file >> word;       //grab a word from the file one at a time
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), 
            ::tolower);     //automatically change words to lowercase
        newList.insertWord(word);
        size++;             //increment size
        //cout << word <<'\n';  //print word - for debugging
    }

    newList.printWordCloud();   //print word cloud - debugging - works
    cout << size << '\n';       //print size - for debugging - works

    file.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

And here is my main:

```
int main(){
    string myFile = "words.txt";
    wordCloud getList;

    //For debugging
    //list.insertWord("word");
    //list.insertWord("more");

    getList.loadWordCloud(myFile);
}
```

This program is far from done. I am also going to have to find out how do do the word frequencies, and delete a node when a word shows up twice, but for right now, I just want to know how I print from main.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: In `loadWordCloud` you load into a temporary instead of the current object. That is why. Get rid of `newList`.

Comment: This definitely worked. So simply.  However this threw off my size count.  The file has 472 words, and when I got rid of newList, now my size count is 944, so it doubled. Can you point me to why it is doubling now?

Comment: I've written this up as an answer, and adjusted for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `loadWordCloud` you have a local variable that you are loading into. Instead, you should be loading the current object. This way, the `getList` variable would have the correct contents.

```
void wordCloud::loadWordCloud(string fileName)
{
    ifstream file;          //variable for fileName
    string word;

    file.open(fileName);    //open file

    while (!file.eof()){
        file >> word;       //grab a word from the file one at a time
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), 
            ::tolower);     //automatically change words to lowercase
        insertWord(word);
        //Don't increment size here, insertWord does this! size++;
        //cout << word <<'\n';  //print word - for debugging
    }
    printWordCloud();   //print word cloud - debugging - works
    cout << size << '\n';       //print size - for debugging - works

    file.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

You also need to remove the `size++`, since `insertWord` will do this for you (otherwise you get `size` double the quantity of words).

If you want to call `loadWordCloud` multiple times and want to clear the list instead of adding, you should add a function to clear the list and call `delete` on all of the nodes. You should also re-use that code for your destructor.

Comment: Yes, I want clear it. This fix doubles my list for some reason. How would I go about avoiding that?

Comment: Did you see the update to not do `size++`? The question is if you actually have double the items or have not yet removed the `size++` in `loadWordCloud`. That would double the value in `size`.

Comment: Oh crap, didn't see I was doing size twice. Thanks for the help!!!!! I appreciate it. Something so small fouling me up.